# BigQuery nested fields: column units of type ARRAY cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to select unique rows of a table in BigQuery but I get the following error: "Column units of type ARRAY cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT".

My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from <table>
```

Table schema

```
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "company_name",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "vat_number",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "industry",
    "type": "RECORD"
  }
```

How can I select distinct rows of a table with nested fields in BigQuery?

Comment: Hey @juta, have you found a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ANY_VALUE function to select the nested field values in a GROUP BY (assuming this value is the same for the entire group):

```
SELECT
  company_name,
  vat_number,
  ANY_VALUE(industry) AS industry
FROM
  <table>
GROUP BY
  company_name,
  vat_number
```